# error message Uncaught (in promise) , but I can't find what's wrong with that after add catch function

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch, fetch-api, thenable

Why does added catch still not work at all?

```js
function maxRequest(url = ``, times = 3) {
  // closure
  function autoRetry (url, times) {
    console.log('times = ', times);
    times--;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(url).then(value => {
        if(value.status === 200) {
          console.log(`✅ `, value);
          resolve(value);
        } else {
          throw new Error(`❌  http code error: ${value.status }`);
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(`❌  Error`, err);
        if (times < 1) {
          reject('  over max request times!');
        } else {
          autoRetry(url, times);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  return autoRetry(url, times);
}

maxRequest(`https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/json/badges.js`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
      console.log('json =', json);
      return json;
  }, err => {
      console.log('error =', err);
      throw new Error(err);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(`err =`, err))
  .finally(() => {
      console.log('whatever close loading...');
  });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the [explicit Promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) masks the fact that you don't return from your `catch` block. In a retry situation, you create a second-try Promise by calling `autoRetry`, but you don't do anything with it, so the `catch` block in your *call* to `maxRequest` doesn't protect you and you wind up with an uncaught rejected Promise.

```js
function maxRequest(url = ``, times = 3) {
  // closure
  function autoRetry (url, times) {
    console.log('times = ', times);
    times--;
    // No more `new Promise`, just a chain.
    return fetch(url).then(value => {
      if(value.status === 200) {
        console.log(`✅ `, value);
        return value;
      } else {
        throw new Error(`❌  http code error: ${value.status }`);
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(`❌  Error`, err);
      if (times < 1) {
        // Converted to rejection. You could still throw a
        // string, but throwing an Error is more idiomatic.
        throw new Error('  over max request times!');
      } else {
        // Make sure to return your Promise here. Don't worry
        // about returning a Promise; it's automatically wrapped
        // like Promise.resolve() does, so this chained-fetch()
        // Promise eventually gets the same result as the returned
        // recursive Promise.
        return autoRetry(url, times);
      }
    });
  }
  return autoRetry(url, times);
}

maxRequest(`https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/json/badges.js`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
      console.log('json =', json);
      return json;
  }, err => {
      console.log('error =', err);
      throw new Error(err);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(`err =`, err))
  .finally(() => {
      console.log('whatever close loading...');
  });
```

For readability's sake, you might also want to change the variable names, so `times` isn't used for both the outer and inner scope. You might also rephrase this as a much shorter `async` function that loops.

[image]

Comment: That's works, Thanks for your time!